# Spring Boot ignore data.sql when running unit tests

Tags: spring-boot, junit

I'm trying to do Unit tests on my Spring Boot repository, but my tests will fail and return `javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement`. I've managed to isolate the problem and it seems to be my `data.sql` in my resources folder that inhibits my tests from running. It seems that having a prebuilt database creates problems when Spring testing.

Now, I can solve the problem by going into my `application.properties` file and setting `spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always` to `=never` instead. But I would rather be able to only turn off that property while running unit tests.

So my question is if it's possible to ignore the `data.sql` file or to set `spring.datasource.initialization-mode=never` within the test class?

Here's my test class below.

```
@RunWith (SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class BikeRepositoryTest {

@Autowired
TestEntityManager entityManager;

@Autowired
BikeRepository bikeRepo;

@Test
public void testFindAll() {
    Bike bike = dummyBike();
    entityManager.persist(bike);
    entityManager.flush();

    List<Bike> bikeList = bikeRepo.findAll();

    assertEquals(bikeList.size(), 1);
    assertThat(bikeList.contains(bike));
}


public static Bike dummyBike() {
    var bike = new Bike();
    bike.setName("gustav");
    bike.setModel("red_dragon");
    bike.setPurchasePrice(BigDecimal.valueOf(456));

    return bike;
}   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an `application.properties` file under `src/test/resources` and set the test only properties you would like there. Those configurations should override the main configuration when running tests.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment on Adam's answer for lack of reputation, but :

In `src/test/resources` add an `application.properties` with

```
spring.sql.init.data-locations=test_data.sql
```

In `src/test/resources` add  a `test_data.sql` which cannot be empty for some reason, but a content such as :

```
SELECT 1 AS DUMMY;
```

will appease Spring.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023 and **for Spring Boot 3.1.0** the name of the property is `spring.sql.init.mode`. Setting it to `never` in an **application.properties file under *test/resources*** will disable initialization as long as you are running the tests under the default profile (otherwise, set that property on the correct profile). This is because, as other answers have stated, the properties under the *test* folder will override those under *main*.

This property can take three values, default being `embedded` and the other two `always` and `never`. Default value will only initialize the database if an embedded database is used (e.g. H2), and `always` will , of course, initialize the database under any circumstances.